# SQL - Is it possible to have a Trigger statement with a WHERE clause that is an equality measure

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I'm trying to add a counter to one of my tables. So far I have these tables

```
Heroes {hero_id, hero_name, villain_id, team_id}
Villains {villain_id, villain_name, team_id}
Teams {team_id, team_name, no_of_members}
```

I want to create a trigger that updates the member count whenever a person is added to a team. So far i have something like this but it keeps giving me Trigger compilation errors. I have seen other instances where people have used WHERE clauses in triggers but they arent similar to my problem. If anyone could tell me why this isnt compiling or what I'm doing wrong I'd be very grateful.

```
CREATE TRIGGER team_no_inc 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Heroes
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Teams SET no_of_members = no_of_members + 1 
    FROM Heroes, Teams WHERE Teams.team_id = Heroes.team_id;
END;
.
RUN;
```

Comment: I'm using SQLPLUS

Comment: While @ypercube has given a techinical solution to the immediate question, your design is fundamentally flawed.  On of the basics of db design is not never store something that can be calculated at run time.  You need to add a 'team members' table.  Instead of trying to store the number of members of a team, just count the number of members when you need that number.  I guarantee if you store your count it will get off, and without an actual list of members (the members table) it's really a meaningless number anyway.

Comment: `UPDATE ... FROM...` is not valid SQL syntax; you may want to check the manual.

Comment: @EdStevens I can completely see your point, it is essentially a meaningless value, but for the assignment and the purpose of the inclusion of triggers I thought it would be ok. Having seen assignments from previous years (some of which given as reccomended reading) which include a run-time counter, it just seemed to fit here.

Comment: @mustaccio, you can write for example `UPDATE (select no_of_members, team_id from Teams) set no_of_members = no_of_members + 1 WHERE ...`

Comment: @roughosing - so this is just a homework assignment?  So what was the _actual_ assigned requirement (not your pre-selected solution)?

Comment: The required assingment was to build a databse and include the use of features that were presented in the lectures (i.e. basic commands (CREATE, INSERT etc)TRIGGER Commands and Security commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle triggers, you can access the modified table using `:NEW` (for inserted and after an update data) and `:OLD` (for deleted and before the update).

Also there is no`UPDATE .. FROM` syntax. Your trigger can be written:

```
CREATE TRIGGER team_no_inc 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Heroes
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Teams SET no_of_members = no_of_members + 1 
    WHERE Teams.team_id = :NEW.team_id;
END;
```

Tested at [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=831563dd1c722cc6454ec1621f588b5d).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I had a feeling the FROM command wasn't valid in this context, although the :New.team_id, that is referring to the team_id in the heroes table correct?

Comment: Yes, it refers to the team_id of the table that activates the trigger, which is heroes.